# AUCTeX toggle math modes

Tags: emacs, auctex

I use `$ ... $` for inline math and `\[ ... \]` for display math. I'd like to be able to toggle between the two by selecting the text and calling `TeX-insert-dollar`.

However, as I understand it, this function only allows the cycles

```
$ ... $ <-> $$ ... $$ <-> ...
```

and

```
\( ... \) <-> \[ ... \] <-> ...
```

(this behaviour is controlled by setting the variable `TeX-electric-math`).

Is there any way to customize this behaviour to my needs (it would also be useful to extend it to other equation enviroments such as `equation`, `align`, `gather`, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to do this like so

```
(defun begin-end-regexps (env)
  (list env
        (replace-regexp-in-string "{\\([a-zA-Z]+\\)\\*}" "{\\1\\\\*}" (concat "\\\\begin{" env "}\\([^\0]*?\\)\\\\end{" env "}"))
        (concat "\\\\begin{" env "}\\1\\\\end{" env "}")))

(defun loop-math-modes (step)
  (if (texmathp)
      (let
          ((math-modes (list '("$" "\\$\\([^$\0]+?\\)\\$" "$\\1$")
                             '("\\[" "\\\\\\[\\([^\0]*?\\)\\\\\\]" "\\\\[\\1\\\\]")
                             (begin-end-regexps "equation")
                             (begin-end-regexps "equation*")
                             (begin-end-regexps "align")
                             (begin-end-regexps "align*")
                             (begin-end-regexps "gather")
                             (begin-end-regexps "gather*")))
           commands)

        (dolist (element math-modes) ;; get list of cars
          (setq commands
                (append commands (list (car element)))))
        (let
            ((math-mode-index (cl-position (car texmathp-why) commands :test 'equal))
             (current-pos (point)))
            (goto-char (cdr texmathp-why)) ;; for some reason save-excursion is not working
            (re-search-forward (nth 1 (nth math-mode-index math-modes)))
            (replace-match (nth 2 (nth (mod (+ math-mode-index step) (length math-modes)) math-modes)))
            (goto-char current-pos)))
    (message "Not inside math environment")))
```

(see [here](https://gitlab.com/marco-venuti/emacs-config/blob/26bbe97cf6764f11817366b2b92d5626d8e58b65/latex.el))